# How to create grok patten for apache access logs to used with AWS Athena to create table

Tags: amazon-athena, grok

I need to create table in AWS Athena for Apache access logs. I tried below query but it fails. The grok parsing string seems to work well separately but when running in Athena it fails.

Note: I need the time stamp to be without square brackets.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_logs.apache_lightsail2`(
  client_ip string,
  client_id string,
  user_id string,
  timestamp2 string,
  client_request string,
  server_status string,
  returned_obj_size string
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE
   'com.amazonaws.glue.serde.GrokSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'input.format'='^%{IPV4:client_ip} %{DATA:client_id} %{USERNAME:user_id} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp2}\] %{QUOTEDSTRING:client_request} %{DATA:server_status} %{DATA:returned_obj_size}$'
   )
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
   's3://my-accesslogs/apache-access-logs/';
```

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape
> sequence near index 268
> ^((?<![0-9])(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})...)(?![0-9]))
> (.*?) ([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)
> [((?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])/\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\b/(?>\d\d){1,2}:(?!<[0-9])(?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::(?:(?:[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?))(?![0-9])
> (?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+)))]
> ((?>(?<!\)(?>"(?>\.|[^\"]+)+"|""|(?>'(?>\.|[^\']+)+')|''|(?>`(?>\\.|[^\\`]+)+`)|``)))
> (.*?) (.*?)$ ^